# Return all models from mongodb as an object or array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am using sockets with mongodb, for a user who is trying to create a new name, I need to check all the models in the database to see if it exists.

I am doing it all wrong, basically I am trying to do something like this.

```
var allUsers = [];

models.Message.find({}, function(err, data) {
    for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
        allUsers.push(data[i].username);
    }
});

console.log(allUsers)
```

I'm sitting here struggling even getting the `allUsers` out of the function, and I am thinking this is not even the best way to do this. With `allUsers` I was just going to check to see if the new username existed in the array.

So to futher extend what I am doing here is some socket.io code. I was going to run some validation like this if I could get the `allUsers` to work.

```
socket.on('new user', function (data, callback) {

    if(data in allUsers) {
        callback(false);
    } else {
        callback(true);
        socket.userName = data;
        socket.connected = true;
        users[socket.userName] = socket;
        io.sockets.emit('user name', {usernames: users[socket.userName].userName, connected: users[socket.userName].connected});
    }

});
```

But without it working, this is no good. So my question is with what I have provided (socket.io, mongodb) how do I get all the models and validate if a new user which is passed in `data` exists in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`models.Message.find` is async, the result of the async operation is only available when the async operation has finished.so  `console.log(allUsers)` will always yield an empty array.

should be something like (pseudo js code):

```
socket.on('new user', function (data, callback) {

    models.User.findOne({username:data.username},function(err,user){
        if(err){/*deal with error here */}
        else if(user){/*username already taken 
            respond with appropriate socket message here */
                socket.emit('user name already taken',{somemessage});
        }
        else{/* user with username not found */
            /*create new user into database then emit socket message */
            var user = new models.User(data);
            user.save(function(err,user){
                socket.emit('user name',{somemessage});
            })
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This is perfect, I had to make some adjustments and do some stuff on the client side.. my testing process is slow, I keep manually restarting node server/ keep running gulp browserify.. I need to work on a faster dev process... I noticed you changed some of my `Message` names to `User` you are right it should be that I was going to change it but initially I built the messaging portion then added in users, so some naming is off... thanks though